# NSUserDefaults Boolean returns false when using app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-extension

I am using Notification Extension in my application to change the notification sound.

When the user turns off the `UISwitch` in the settings page I save in the `NSUserDefaults` a `boolean` to keep tracking of the state.

However I have 2 different storyboards for two different languages, each has its own style.

When I am using the storyboard A and I print the state of the `boolean` in the console, it's printing the state correctly. But when I change the language hence a different storyboard B loads up. The `boolean` is always returning `false`.

Although the boolean always return `false`, I have tested the sound of the notification, it works correctly.

Any idea why the `boolean` is always returning `false`? I need the correct value in order to show the state correctly of the ringtone in the settings page.

Here's the code I am using:

```
- (void)setPlayDefaultSound:(BOOL)playDefaultSound
{
    NSUserDefaults *def = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.xx.xxx.NotificationServices"];
    [def setBool:playDefaultSound forKey:@"playDefaultSound"];
    [def synchronize];
}
- (BOOL)playDefaultSound
{
    NSUserDefaults *def = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.xx.xxx.NotificationServices"];
    return [def boolForKey:@"playDefaultSound"];
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the Info.plist of the Notification Services Extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instances of NSUserDefaults each time. Use the same instance each time.

Use this instead.

```
- (void)setPlayDefaultSound:(BOOL)playDefaultSound
{

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:playDefaultSound forKey:@"playDefaultSound"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
- (BOOL)playDefaultSound
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"playDefaultSound"];
}
```

Comment: This for inside the app not when sharing between app and extension

Comment: @Sh_Khan What do you mean?

Comment: @Skywalker what you are proposing is the way of using the NSUserDefaults inside the application, while the way of initializing it as I did is to share between the app and the app extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch in the name in the capabilities, a typo.

It's working normally now.

Comment: If the problem was a typo, then this question will not help any future readers.. please delete this question